# concurrency in multiple core

Tags: operating-systems, parallel-computing, concurrency, threads

I know the basic definition between parallelism and concurrency. But there is not much information about
concurrency in multiple core.

what is the difference between concurrency in single-core vs concurrency in multiple-core?

Is there much difference **performance-wise** between concurrency in multiple core vs parallelism in multiple core?

Comment: concurrency in multiple cores is usually faster (it depends on your algorithm, and how you use locks) than in a single core. That being said, a non-concurrent program will run the same time on a single and multiple cores (but you may feel a difference in running time due to other processes interfering less with the time your process has)

Comment: how can you say a non-concurrent program takes same time in single and multiple cores? Doesn't cpu with multiple core will help program run to run faster?

Comment: @Rohit: How many cores are there? And how many cores _are used_? These are totally different questions with totally different answers. A program doesn't use multiple cores unless explicitly told so.

Answer (score 1):

Modern multi-core processors are parallel.

First I want to explain why a single core processor (no hyper threading) offers instruction-level parallelism.

First they have pipelined-parallelism, so they have multiple instructions from a single instruction stream at various stages in the pipeline. So in the typical cs literature you will see the 5 stages of a RISC processor:

- fetch
- decode
- execute
- memory access
- write back (write changes to memory/registers).

But modern processors have many more stages. Modern Intel processors have between 16-20 stages and older ones even had more.

Another dimension of instruction-level parallelism is super scalar execution. A processor has a few hundred instructions in its scheduling window (ROB) and it will execute instructions out of order as long as the input dependencies of the instructions are met (look for Tomasulo algorithm). So if there are a set of instructions that are independent of each other, these can be execute in parallel on different execution units. E.g. a Skylake has 4 ALU's and these can be run truly in parallel. So if a single add takes 1 clock cycle, in a single clock cycle you could do 4 adds.

Apart from instruction-level parallelism, there is thread-level parallelism: so parallelism due to having multiple instruction streams as you can see on SMT and SMP systems.

The nice thing about SMT that the CPU has multiple instruction streams to pick instructions from; so there is a greater chance that instructions can run in parallel based on functionality I explained above.

And the last one is SMP where there are multiple CPUs in a single package (aka multicore)

Answer (score 0):

Concurrency is not parallelism: indeed, concurrency refers to the sharing of resources in the same time frame. As an example, several processes may share the same CPU or share memory or an I/O device.

Two processes (or threads) can be defined concurrent if an only if the second process starts execution before the first has terminated (assuming that the execution happens on the same core of a multi-core CPU).

Therefore, if the two processes both run on the same core of a multi-core CPU the processes are concurrent but not parallel: in this case, parallelism is only virtual and refers to the OS doing timesharing. The OS seems to be executing several processes simultaneously. But, since the processes execute on the same core, only one instruction from one process can be executing at any particular time. Since the human time scale is billions of times slower than that of modern computers, the OS can rapidly switch between processes to give the appearance of several processes executing at the same time.

If you instead run the two processes on two different CPUS, the processes are parallel: there is no sharing in the same time frame, because each process runs on its own CPU. The parallelism in this case is not virtual but physical.

Finally, it is worth noting here that two processes running on different cores of the same multi-core CPU can not be classified as fully parallel, because the processes share the same CPU caches and will even contend for them.

It should now be clear that performance-wise, parallelism is better than concurrency.

Comment: thanks Massimo. small doubt from a website that says "Concurrency is running multiple threads which share some data (or interfere: overlap their executions on some code). These threads cannot safely run without proper communication (synchronization). Sometimes it is referred as running multiple threads in a single core but that's not entirely accurate. The threads can run in multiple cores but they have to do proper synchronization between each other to achieve the goals." So if multiple thread run on multiple core according to above para will it be concurrent or parallel or both?

Comment: It depends, e.g.: 1) multiple threads belonging to the same process or to different processes, one thread per core -> parallel 2) multiple threads belonging to the same process or to different processes, two or more threads per core ->  both parallel and concurrent.

Comment: Thanks Massimo. One last small doubt "If I assume that multiple threads of conncurrent proceess run in parallel."

Then which is better performance-wise concurrency in multi-core vs parallelism in multi-core and why?

Comment: Your question is not meaningful, you need to carefully read my answer.